# Is it possible to disable in NFS showing name of shared folder?

Tags: linux, security, nfs, qnap

I have NFS server 192.168.1.1 and two client servers  192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.3. On nfs server I have one shared nfs folder
/etc/exports:

```
/nfsshare 192.168.1.2(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

As you see only client 192.168.1.2 can acces that folder, but executing

```
showmount -e 192.168.1.1
```

from any of clients servers end up showing the list of shared folders from server 192.168.1.1 and I want to prevent that. Is it possible and if it is possible  how to configure that?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1039497/nfs-share-hide-directories-and-folders-for-users-without-permission

Answer (score 1):

The **showmount** command talks to **mountd** process. If you use NFSv4, then clients don't require mountd and you can stop it. If you need provide NFSv3 service, then you can enforce mountd to run on a dedicated port (in /etc/nfs.conf) and protect it with firewall rules.